# Why this code does not schow the complete XML-Node using $node->asXML()

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following code:

```
public function importParameter(){
$xml=simplexml_load_file("./../../SEBAMqualitativ.dat") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$result = $xml->xpath('Parameter/Z');

foreach ($result as $node) {
    Print_r($node);
    Print_r("<br>");
    Print_r("ASXML:");
    print_r($node->asXML());
    print_r("<hr>");
}
}
```

and the following output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [Code] => 3013 
            [Text] => Abamectin [µg/l] 
    ) 
)
ASXML:
```

why `$node->AsXML` shows an emtpy string?

The format of XML is like this

```
<Z Code="3013" Text="Abamectin [µg/l]"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    <Z Code="1706" Text="Abbautest/CSB-Abbau [%]"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    <Z Code="1441" Text="Abfiltrierbare Stoffe [mg/l]"/>
```

Comment: Have you viewed the source of the page?  Any XML tags may be taken as HTML tags and so the browser will try and interpret them.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to have the full xml source? just to be able to reproduce the case.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue -> https://onlinephp.io/c/2d682